# Does \newpage reliably trigger shipout. as in \AtBeginShipout?

Tags: atbegshi, shipout

Although I am using TeXlive 2016 with LuaTeX, single-column double-sided pages in a custom document class, I believe this question applies to nearly everything:

I am aware that the page shipout routine is asynchornous, and I understand why: It is because the page break is not really nailed down until the layout engine has a look at what might flow to the next page.

My question: Does the `\newpage` command reliably trigger shipout, right there? In other words, suppose I do something like this, as part of a larger document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\newif\ifmytestflag \mytestflagfalse
\AtBeginShipout{\mytestflagfalse}
\begin{document}
... some text.\mytestflagtrue
\newpage
HERE ... more text
\end{document}
```

Can I be sure that `\mytestflag` is always false, at HERE ? I would like to place a test there, and it is vital that the flag be set correctly. The test cannot be postponed until later on the page; it must be at the top.

Of course, I have tried a few examples. Seems OK. But I do not know whether I was merely lucky.

Note: I am definitely not using math mode.

EDIT: After another cup of coffee, my brain unfroze, and I saw the light: The easiest thing to do is to re-define `\newpage` by prepending a macro that clears my flag. So simple and obvious. Then I do not need to worry about when `\AtBeginShipout` happens. But since not everyone likes to re-define essential commands, perhaps they would like to know the answer to my original question.

Comment: `\newpage` does not necessarily trigger the output of a page: If the vertical list is empty, then nothing is output. Or it just starts a new column in a two-column layout.

Comment: It is quite unclear to me, what and where you want to test via the flag switch.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Your "does not necessarily" answers my question. I encourage you to place it as answer. As for what and where I wanted to test, that would involve a pile of code that would obscure a MWE. In essence: If a particular macro is used, it sets a flag that prevents re-use of the same macro, until AtBeginShipout clears it. The clearance can be delayed when shipout is asynchronous. But it must be immediate at newpage. My own edit, above, revealed the most obvious way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\newpage` does not necessarily trigger the output of a page:

- If the vertical list is empty, then nothing is output.
- Or it just starts a new column in a two-column layout.

---

A test, whether a macro is called more than once on the same page can be implemented via references. Package `zref-perpage` offers an interface with a counter, that is reset at the start of each page. The method needs at least two LaTeX runs. Example file:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{zref-perpage}

\newcounter{mymacro}
\zmakeperpage{mymacro}
\newcommand*{\mymacro}{%
  \stepcounter{mymacro}%
  \ifnum\value{mymacro}=1 %
    % First usage of \mymacro on the page
    \textcolor{red}{[\themymacro]}%
  \else
    % Second or later usage of \mymacro on the page
    \textcolor{blue}{[\themymacro]}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\mymacro~\lipsum[1]
\mymacro~\lipsum[2]
\mymacro~\lipsum[3]
\mymacro~\lipsum[4]
\mymacro~\lipsum[5]
\mymacro~\lipsum[6]
\mymacro~\lipsum[7]
\mymacro~\lipsum[8]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Page 1]  [image: Page 2]  [image: Page 3]

Comment: Very authoritative! I don't use two columns, but others might. I had not thought of `\newpage` followed by an empty vertical list, but it could happen.